# How to know vertex weight of Lattice?

Tags: interface, vertex-weights, lattice

I have Lattice with weighted vertex group. I'd like to know exact weight of vertices like you usually do it with meshes (`N-Panel`), but unfortunately this data isn't available for Lattice. Any workaround?